# custom dimension naming convention?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Is there a general naming convention for ga custom dimensions? It seems that the purpose of a custom dimension is to track some type of special usage scenario.  So let's say that you want to track user behavior for MyWidget. Would you name your custom dimension "MyWidgetUsageScenario"? Or do most GA devs take a more literal/direct approach and name this custom dimension MyWidgetDimension?﻿

Answer (score 0):

I would lean towards: OBJECT_ACTION.

So in this case, MyWidget_PassThrough (or whatever specific action is being tracked).